# How does these square roots work?

Tags: arithmetic

$$\tag{1}2\sqrt{90} - 5\sqrt{160} + 3\sqrt{250} - 2\sqrt{40} = ?$$

$$\tag{2}\sqrt[3]{a\cdot b^2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{a^3 \cdot b \cdot c^2} = ?$$

$$\tag{3}\frac 6{2 \cdot \sqrt{3} - 3} = ?$$

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tH62.jpg)

Comment: Could you please adjust with Latex?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the first time this website and I'm not sure how to write formulas here, so I added an image..

Comment: here is a helpful definiton $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Comment: Definition. The square root of any proposed expression is that quantity whose square, or second power, is equal to the given expression.

Comment: @Vikram This is the definition of "a" square root. "The" square root of a nonnegative real is the only nonegative one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tag{1}\begin{align} &2\sqrt{90} - 5\sqrt{160} + 3\sqrt{250} - 2\sqrt{40} \\ \\ & = 2\sqrt{9 \cdot 10} - 5\sqrt{16\cdot 10} + 3\sqrt{25\cdot 10} - 2\sqrt{4 \cdot 10} \\ \\ & = 2\cdot \sqrt 9 \cdot \sqrt {10} - 5\sqrt{16}{\sqrt 10} + 3\sqrt{25} \cdot \sqrt {10} - 2 \sqrt 4 \cdot \sqrt {10} \\ \\ &= ?\end{align}$$

---

$$\tag{2}\sqrt[3]{a\cdot b^2} \cdot \sqrt[4]{a^3 \cdot b \cdot c^2} = ?$$

For (2), use the fact that $\sqrt[\large n]{a} = a^{1/n}$, and use the laws of exponents, in particular, use the following rules:  $$(ab)^c = a^c\cdot b^c$$ $$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$$ $$a^b\cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$$

---

$$\tag{3}\frac 6{2 \cdot \sqrt{3} - 3} = ?$$

For (3), rationalize the denominator: multiply both the numerator and denominator by $2 \cdot \sqrt 3 + 3$, and recall that when we multiply factors of the form$(a-b)(a+b)$, we obtain a difference of squares: $$(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$$

Answer (score 0):

For $(1)$, you could take the root partially, ie. $\sqrt{90} = 3 * \sqrt{10}$ and so on for the others.

For $(2)$, consider $\sqrt[3]{a} = a^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $\sqrt[4]{a^3} = a^{\frac{3}{4}}$.

For $(3)$, consider multiplying the denominator with $2 \cdot \sqrt{3} + 3$ and use the binomial formula $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$.

Comment: Alright, well, for the second one I get: a^(1/3) * b^(2/3) * a^(3/4) * b^(1/4) * c^(2/4), so, to add them together, I have to sum the powers (doesn't matter if they don't have the same base)?

Comment: Not Well at least $a^{1/3}$ and $a^{3/4}$ do have the same base ;-) Maybe you can find more of pairs like this.

Answer (score 0):

[1]$$2\sqrt90-5\sqrt{160}+3\sqrt{250}-2\sqrt{40}=$$
$$=2\cdot3\sqrt{10}-5\cdot4\sqrt{10}+ 3\cdot5\sqrt{10}-2\cdot2\sqrt{10}=$$
$$=-\sqrt{10}$$
[2]
$$\sqrt[3]{ab^2}\sqrt[4]{a^3bc^2}=\sqrt[3\cdot4]{(ab^2)^4}\sqrt[4\cdot3]{(a^3bc^2)^3}=$$
$$=\sqrt[12]{a^4b^8}\sqrt[12]{a^9b^3c^6}=\sqrt[12]{a^{13}b^{11}c^6} $$
[3]
$$\frac{6}{2\sqrt3-3}=\frac{6(2\sqrt3+3)}{(2\sqrt3-3)(2\sqrt3+3)}=$$
$$=\frac{6(2\sqrt3+3)}{12-9}=\frac{6(2\sqrt3+3)}{3}=2(2\sqrt3+3)  $$

Comment: What happens to c in 2nd one?

Comment: Shouldn't your 2nd term in the 1st line be 5*Sqrt(160)?

Comment: answer is edited